# Oracle , parametros das procedures de um Owner

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g

No Oracle qual a tabela ou view do metadados em que tenho os parâmetros de uma Procedure.

Minha dúvida é , que *procedures* TEM parâmetros com o nome parecido com "XPTO" ?

Tentei pela "dict" mas não achei.

Answer (score 3):

Voce poderia fazer assim:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM ALL_OBJECTS A
  LEFT JOIN ALL_ARGUMENTS B
   ON A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID
  WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('PROCEDURE') AND 
    B.ARGUMENT_NAME = 'XPTO'
```

Comment: Right on the money !! Perfeito "arguments" eu buscava por "parameters"